# ¿Como puedo realizar esta operacion?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php7

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
                     <?php if($cart->total_items() > 0){ ?>
                        <td class="text-center"><strong>Total <?php 
                        
                        $Pmenos = ($cart->total()*10)/100;

                        $resta = $cart->total() - $Pmenos;

                        $cart->total() = $resta;
                        
                        echo '$'.$cart->total().' MEX'; 
                        
                        
                       ?>
```

Me manda el siguiente error.

**Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in C:\xampp\htdocs\p\Pagos.php on line 335**

Es una operacion donde estoy haciendo la resta del porcentaje de tal cantidad, pero al momento de que quiero que mi $cart->total() sea igual a = $resta me manda ese error y no se como arreglarlo.

Sin en cambio si nadamas pongo `echo echo '$'.$resta.' MEX';` no me da error pero en la base de datos me pone el numero sin la resta del porcentaje.

Comment: ¿Qué hay en tu método `total()`?

Comment: es una pagina de venta de pasteles, al momento de seleccionar 1 o mas, el total es la cantidad a pagar

Comment: Ya, pero esto es una llamada a un método: `$cart->total()` ¿Qué hay en ese método? Tampoco se entiende lo que quieres decir con esto: *no me da error pero en la base de datos me pone el numero sin la resta del porcentaje.* Pulsa en [edit] y completa la pregunta.

Comment: pastel 1 - $100 - pastel 2 - $200 $cart->total() = $300

Comment: No se entiende. Se supone que tienes algo como esto: **`function total () { //aquí código }`** Es por ese código por el que te estoy preguntando.

Comment: En `$cart->total() = $resta;` ¿Asignar un valor a una función?

Comment: @Sal se supone que le da el valor de $resta, ¿no?

Comment: @AlejandroFernando pon lo que dice A. Cedano, ya que es necesario mostralo para poder ayudarte

Comment: @Alejandro No, las funciones no son asignables. Tendría que ser `$cart->total = $resta` si es un atributo accesible ó algo como `$cart->total($resta)` si tiene setter.